# Finding an specific node in a XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, menu, nodes, descendant

I have a XML with 5 or 6 levels. All nodes has an unique ID. By this ID, I need to find a specif node and create a list showing only the ancestors of this node. 
I'll try to explain better with codes:

That's my XML with all options:

```
<MenuConfig>
<Menu name="name-1" location="location 1" title="Menu 1">
    <Item name="name-1.1" location="location 1.1.jsp" title="Menu 1.1"/>
    <Item name="name-1.2" location="location 1.2.jsp" title="Menu 1.2"/>
    <Item name="name-1.3" location="location 1.3.jsp" title="Menu 1.3">
        <Item name="name-1.3.1" location="location 1.3.1.jsp" title="Menu 1.3.1"/>
        <Item name="name-1.3.2" location="location 1.3.2.jsp" title="Menu 1.3.2"/>
    </Item>
    <Item name="name-1.4" location="location 1.4.jsp" title="Menu 1.3">
        <Item name="name-1.4.1" location="location 1.4.1.jsp" title="Menu 1.4.1"/>
        <Item name="name-1.4.2" location="location 1.4.2.jsp" title="Menu 1.4.2"/>
    </Item>
</Menu>
<Menu name="name-2" location="location 2" title="Menu 2">
    <Item name="name-2.1" location="location 2.1.jsp" title="Menu 2.1"/>
    <Item name="name-2.2" location="location 2.2.jsp" title="Menu 2.2"/>
    <Item name="name-2.3" location="location 2.3.jsp" title="Menu 2.3">
        <Item name="name-2.3.1" location="location 2.3.1.jsp" title="Menu 2.3.1"/>
        <Item name="name-2.3.2" location="location 2.3.2.jsp" title="Menu 2.3.2"/>
    </Item>
    <Item name="name-2.4" location="location 2.4.jsp" title="Menu 2.3">
        <Item name="name-2.4.1" location="location 2.4.1.jsp" title="Menu 2.4.1"/>
        <Item name="name-2.4.2" location="location 2.4.2.jsp" title="Menu 2.4.2"/>
    </Item>
</Menu>
<Menu name="name-3" location="location 3" title="Menu 3">
    <Item name="name-3.1" location="location 3.1.jsp" title="Menu 3.1"/>
    <Item name="name-3.2" location="location 3.2.jsp" title="Menu 3.2"/>
    <Item name="name-3.3" location="location 3.3.jsp" title="Menu 3.3">
        <Item name="name-3.3.1" location="location 3.3.1.jsp" title="Menu 3.3.1"/>
        <Item name="name-3.3.2" location="location 3.3.2.jsp" title="Menu 3.3.2"/>
    </Item>
    <Item name="name-3.4" location="location 3.4.jsp" title="Menu 3.3">
        <Item name="name-3.4.1" location="location 3.4.1.jsp" title="Menu 3.4.1">
            <Item name="name-3.4.1.1" location="location 3.4.1.1.jsp" title="Menu 3.4.1.1"/>
            <Item name="name-3.4.1.2" location="location 3.4.1.2.jsp" title="Menu 3.4.1.2"/>
        </Item>
        <Item name="name-3.4.2" location="location 3.4.2.jsp" title="Menu 3.4.2">
            <Item name="name-3.4.2.1" location="location 3.4.2.1.jsp" title="Menu 3.4.2.1"/>
            <Item name="name-3.4.2.2" location="location 3.4.2.2.jsp" title="Menu 3.4.2.2"/>
        </Item>
    </Item>
</Menu>
</Menu>
</MenuConfig>
```

That's the XSLT that I'm trying to create:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="menu"/>

<xsl:template match="/MenuConfig/Menu">
    <div id="data-sidebar">
        <ul class="sidebar list-unstyled">
            <li>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:if test="@name = $menu">active</xsl:if>
            </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="a">
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@location"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item[not(Item)]">
    <li>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:if test="@name = $menu">active</xsl:if>
    </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="@location"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item[Item]">
    <li>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:if test="@name = $menu">active</xsl:if>
    </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="@location"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Item" />
        </ul>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have this external param "menu" where I'll get the current list position (name property)

Let's imagine that the name param is "name-3.4.1.2". In this case, I should show the menu-3 only, the menu-3.4, menu-3.4.1 and children and menu-3.4.2 (sibling of 3.4.1) but without the children. Maybe (it's not confirmed yet by my business manager) I should show only 3 or 4 ancestors levels. Like, if the menu selected is level 6 (1.2.3.4.5.6), I must show up to level 3 (1.2.3) only.

I have no idea how to do it. My real XML is deeper than that and it could be indefinitely deep.

Sorry if I'm not clear enough, but I can't explain better.

Thanks guys...

EDIT:
It's the expected output. It's a HTML:

```
  <div id="data-sidebar">
        <ul class="sidebar list-unstyled">
            <li class=""><a href="location 3.jsp">Menu 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class=""><a href="location 3.4.jsp">Menu 3.4</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class=""><a href="location 3.4.1">Menu 3.4.1</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class=""><a href="location 3.4.1.1">Menu 3.4.1.1</a></li>
                                    <li class="active"><a href="location 3.4.1.2">Menu 3.4.1.2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class=""><a href="location 3.4.2">Menu 3.4.2</a></li>
                        </ul
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

At the browser it should appear like this:

- Menu 3

  - Menu 3.4

    - Menu 3.4.1

      - Menu 3.4.1.1
      - ***Menu 3.4.1.2***
    - Menu 3.4.2

Comment: Please show your expected output as XML / XHTML, not as text - it's hard to imagine what the output should look like. Besides, perhaps it would be worth waiting for your business manager to decide things before asking here?

Comment: There are some rules that it will happen independently of their decisions. That rules I'm working on now. I've put the output. It should be clearer now.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not exactly simple, I think you are making it much more complicated than it needs to be. Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="name" select="'name-3.4.1.2'"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::*[@name=$name]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input (corrected for well formedness!) the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MenuConfig>
   <Menu name="name-3" location="location 3" title="Menu 3">
      <Item name="name-3.4" location="location 3.4.jsp" title="Menu 3.3">
         <Item name="name-3.4.1" location="location 3.4.1.jsp" title="Menu 3.4.1">
            <Item name="name-3.4.1.2" location="location 3.4.1.2.jsp" title="Menu 3.4.1.2"/>
         </Item>
      </Item>
   </Menu>
</MenuConfig>
```

Comment: Thanks... It worked. But I need a HTML exit with all divs, etc and with copy it's existing XML. Sorry to ask that, but I'm a little beginner. Thanks

Comment: @Adriano I am afraid I don't what you mean. Please edit your question and show as the expected output **as code**.

Comment: @Adriano I see. Well, this is just a matter of changing the output of the template - instead of `xsl:copy`, output the element/s that you want. It has nothing to do with the real issue here and you'll excuse me if I find it totally uninteresting.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks... Your resolution helped me a lot.. I'll keep working on it.. Thanks!!